# What to use instead of UITextAlignmentRight when positioning the contents of a UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, ios9

In Apples' own documentation,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

it has recommended using UITextAlignmentRight in the following snippet on that page :

```
Listing 5-7  Adding subviews to a cell’s content view
#define MAINLABEL_TAG 1
#define SECONDLABEL_TAG 2
#define PHOTO_TAG 3

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";

    UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
    UIImageView *photo;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)];
        mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

        secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 220.0, 25.0)];
        secondLabel.tag = SECONDLABEL_TAG;
        secondLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

        photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0, 0.0, 80.0, 45.0)];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];
    } else {
        mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINLABEL_TAG];
        secondLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:SECONDLABEL_TAG];
        photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
    }
    NSDictionary *aDict = [self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mainLabel.text = [aDict objectForKey:@"mainTitleKey"];
    secondLabel.text = [aDict objectForKey:@"secondaryTitleKey"];
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[aDict objectForKey:@"imageKey"] ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    photo.image = theImage;

    return cell;
}
```

However, Xcode 7 compains that UITextAlignmentRight has been deprecated since iOS 6.0. However, Xcode does not say what to use in its place. Please recommend what to use instead of UITextAlignmentRight

Comment: Read the docs for `UITextAlignmentRight`. It tells you what to use instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use : NSTextAlignment

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight
```